# css horizantal scroll alignment from right to left

Tags: html, css

I want to align divs from right to left. The default align is left to right

```css
#row {
    white-space: nowrap; /* important */
    overflow: auto;
}
.items {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div id="row">
    <div class="items">
        <img src="//placehold.it/200/100" alt="item 1" />
    </div>
    <div class="items">
        <img src="//placehold.it/200/100" alt="item 2" />
    </div>
</div>
```

If I set `float:right` or `float:left` in `.items` class, horizantal scroll is not appearing and items overflow to bottom (when I add more items in row).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just add [direction](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/direction) **r**ight **t**o **l**eft to `#row`

```css
#row {
    white-space: nowrap; /* important */
    overflow: auto;
    direction: rtl;
}
.items {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
    <div id="row">
        <div class="items">
            <img src="//placehold.it/200/100" alt="item 1" />
        </div>
        <div class="items">
            <img src="//placehold.it/200/100" alt="item 2" />
        </div>
    </div>
```

If you overflow the `#row` container with more `.items`, you will see an horizontal scroll bar.

### Clarification

Apparently, the `text-align: right` also does the same job, but that is not exactly true.

Consider the following markup:

```
<div id="row">
    <div class="items">itemA</div>
    <div class="items">itemB</div>
    <div class="items">itemC</div>
</div>
```

With `direction: rtl;` you get

```
+-------------------------------------------+
|                   | itemC | itemB | itemA |
+-------------------------------------------+
```

With `text-align:right;` you get

```
+-------------------------------------------+
|                   | itemA | itemB | itemC |
+-------------------------------------------+
```

Comment: this works but direction changes position of some contents. For example <h5>✔ Name</h5> is appearing like this: "Name ✔"

Comment: @bookmarker Just change `#row`'s children to `#row *{direction: ltr;}`

Answer (score 0):

You can use display of inline-block on .items and just add text-align to parent element, which in this case is div with class row.

```css
#row {
    white-space: nowrap; /* important */
    overflow: auto;
    text-align: right;/* added line */
}
.items {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div id="row">
    <div class="items">
        <img src="//placehold.it/200/100" alt="item 1" />
    </div>
    <div class="items">
        <img src="//placehold.it/200/100" alt="item 2" />
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

One another option to align from right is give `text-align:right;` to `#row`

```css
#row {
    white-space: nowrap; /* important */
    overflow: auto;
    text-align:right;
}
.items {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div id="row">
    <div class="items">
        <img src="//placehold.it/200/100" alt="item 1" />
    </div>
    <div class="items">
        <img src="//placehold.it/200/100" alt="item 2" />
    </div>
</div>
```